# Make Braintree Drop-In UI work with multiple postback events in ASP.NET web forms page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, braintree

I am trying to integrate the Braintree Drop-in UI into web form pages where I have multiple postback events triggered by different button clicks.  This is required functionality in order to make the process flow smoothly.

However, since the Drop-In UI intercepts the form submission, none of the other events fire properly, only the Page_Load event.  Since you cannot have more than one form in a web form page without disabling event validation, does anyone know of a way to have the Drop-In UI only intercept the form submission from one specific button?  Or if I use the onPaymentMethodReceived function of Braintree.setup, allow it to go ahead and submit the form normally with the nonce to the correct event tied to the specific payment button click?

The Braintree logic works, I just now have no good way of making my existing postback events work alongside it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to go back in and add my resolution way back when.  See below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the details are a bit rusty, but the answer was...

For the non-braintree postbacks, add the following to the button markup:

- UseSubmitBehavior="false"
- OnClick="btnNonBraintree_Click"

For the Braintree postback button, set:

- UseSubmitBehavior="true"
- OnClick="btnBraintree_Click"

IIRC, I had to define the OnClick on the form (and not use the wireup logic in the codebehind) for this to work properly.  However, the key was the UseSubmitBehavior flags